# Why i get error when use spring input tag

Tags: java, spring, jsp

Whenever i use s:input i get org.apache.jasper.JasperException, i don't know why this doesn't work. Here is my code:

```
<c:forEach var="msg" items="${listMonAn}">
   <s:form action="XuLyThemMon.htm" commandName="chitietdon" method="get" modelAttribute="chitietdon">
      <!--                                        <li><a href="#">-->
      <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6" style="margin-top: 38px;">
         <img src="
         <c:url value="/resource/images/${msg.getMon_hinhAnh()}"/>
         " style="border-radius: 20px;"><br><br>
         <s:input path="name" value="name"></s:input>
         <input type="submit" value="Đặt món" class="btn btn-info"/>
      </div>
      <!--                                            </a></li>-->
   </s:form>
</c:forEach>
```

There code use http://www.springframework.org/tags/form

Comment: provided link doesn't work.

Comment: The error message should give you some indication of the line the error is occuring. I'd suspect it's this line: `<img src="
         <c:url value="/resource/images/${msg.getMon_hinhAnh()}"/>
         " style="border-radius: 20px;">`
I haven't done JSP in over a year, but I'm guessing you can't put a tag in there like that.

Comment: In addition, method calls are unnecessary when accessing getters. `${msg.mon_hinhAnh}` will call the getter method as long as you're following naming conventions for your getters.

Answer (score 0):

Oh, i solved the issue, i just create a bean and import data in it:

```
@ModelAttribute("chitietdon")
    public ChiTietDon getThongTinBan(){
        return new ChiTietDon();
    }
```